# How to check if 2 elements are same in python OOP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```py
class Course:
  def __init__(self, name, classroom, instructor, day, start_time, end_time):
    self.name = name
    self.classroom = classroom
    self.instructor = instructor
    self.day = day
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time

class Schedule:
  def __init__(self):
    self.courses = []
    program = [["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]]

  def add_course(self, course):
    self.courses.append(course)  

  def print_schedule(self):
    days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]
    program = [["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]]
    for course in self.courses:
      for j in range(course.start_time-9,course.end_time-8):
        program[days.index(course.day)][j] += f"      {course.name} class from {course.instructor} at {course.classroom}"
    for i in range(len(days)):
        print(days[i],":")
        for k in program[i]:
          print(k)
        
schedule = Schedule()
schedule.add_course(Course("Physics","MED A11","James","Monday",9,11))
schedule.add_course(Course("Logic Design","EEB 4105","Jack","Wednesday",9,10))
schedule.add_course(Course("Logic Design","EEB 4205","Jack","Wednesday",15,17))

schedule.print_schedule()
```

Here I wanted to create an weekly schedule, I want it to write something when two classes collide. So their self.day need to be same and the times need to intersect.

For times I can do something like

```py
time = {for i in range(start_time,end_time+1)}
if time1.intersection(time2) != 0:
     #...
```

But I don't know how to reach 2 different Course elements at the same time. Also would be great if you have any suggestions for this code.

Comment: So the time can only take integer values? — Even so, why construct a (potentially huge) range? Why not just use two comparisons? `if between(time.start_time, time1.start_time, time1.end_time) or between(time.end_time, time1.start_time, time1.end_time)`, with `between(x, from, to)` defined as `return from <= x <= to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method to the `Course` class that checks it against another `Course` to see if they collide.  When you add a course, have it loop through the existing courses to see if it collides with the existing courses in your `Schedule`.

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, classroom, instructor, day, start_time, end_time):
        self.name = name
        self.classroom = classroom
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.day = day
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

    def check_collision(self, other):
        if self.day == other.day:
            if other.start_time < self.start_time < other.end_time:
                return True
            if other.start_time < self.end_time < other.end_time:
                return True
            if self.start_time < other.start_time < self.end_time:
                return True
            if self.start_time < other.end_time < self.end_time:
                return True
        return False


class Schedule:
    def __init__(self):
        self.courses = []
        self.program = [
            ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
            ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
            ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
            ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
            ["9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
        ]

    def add_course(self, course):
        for c in self.courses:
            if course.check_collision(c):
                print(f'New course has collision with course: {c.name} on {c.day}: {c.start_time}-{c.end_time}')
                break
        else:
            self.courses.append(course)

    def print_schedule(self):
        days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]
        program = [x.copy() for x in self.program]
        for course in self.courses:
            for j in range(course.start_time-9,course.end_time-8):
                program[days.index(course.day)][j] += f"      {course.name} class from {course.instructor} at {course.classroom}"
        for i in range(len(days)):
            print(days[i],":")
            for k in program[i]:
                print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on your Code, what you can do is define a compare function for the class Schedule, you make a Schedule object to hold many courses. So if you want to access a course within a Schedule you need to do schedule.courses[i]. But I suggest you add the following function to the courses class to solve your problem.

```
def compare_course(self, other_course):
my_time = {i for i in range(start_time, end_time+1)}
other_time = {i for i in range(other_course.start_time, other_course.end_time+1)}
if my_time.intersection(other_course.time) != set():
    return "Course Collides"
else:
    return "Course does not collide"
```

Comment: But I want it to be automatic not with another function. When I run the code it has to check the courses whether they collide or not, if they do it shouldn't print the schedule.

Comment: Then you can add all this code inside your add_course function and iterate through your courses in your Schedule class.